# Is there a way to write to the driverstore on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, printing, driver

Why?  Well HP managed to ship two totally different printers, both called the 'Laserjet 6L'.  One supports Postscript, the other only PCL5e.  Now there is no official Windows 10 driver for the PCL5e version but the Windows NT driver supports a number of PCL5e models, including some that are supported on Windows 10.  So I want to try replacing the PS version GDP file on Windows 10 with the PCL5e version and see whether this will convince Windows 10 to use the same driver it uses for the other models to run my printer in the correct manner.  Except that I can't seem to get permission to write to my own hard driver - grrr!

Comment: Why do you want to make changes in DriverStore. Your printer driver might be present in system32/drivers folder.

Comment: It wasn't, or rather didn't appear to be.  But I could at least read the files and was able to figure out what was going on - see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer to my main problem of 'my printer doesn't work' was simpler than it might have been.  There were three errors working together and preventing the supplied Windows 10 drivers from working correctly:

1. Windows 10 has two drivers for an "HP Laserjet 6L" and chose the wrong one.  It installed "HP Laserjet 6L PS", a postscript driver whereas the 6L Pro requires the "HP Laserjet 6L" driver, a PCL5e driver; from printer properties, select the correct driver by hand.
2. Windows 10 has a 'Legacy Plug and Play' option for LPT devices; this printer is old and seems to need this set from Administrative Tools, Component Management, Devices, Ports
3. Windows 10 needs to be explicitly told how much memory the printer has. I have an extra 4MB card so I needed to explicitly tell Windows the printer has 5MB total; set from printer properties again.

Having fixed all of these the printer works.

Comment: A second gotcha, Windows 10 automatically updates drivers unless you stop it.  But in this case it automatically updates to the useless PostScript driver.  So follow the various instructions available that disable driver updates otherwise your printer keeps going haywire!